# Facing issue to connect with GPSD with UART

Tags: gps, embedded-linux, gpsd

We connected L89 GNSS module to processor via UART. I may running `gpsmon` and `gpspipe` commands on board but but not getting NMEA logs. But when we were connected L89 to processor via USB, that time I am getting NMEA logs on `gpsmon` and `gpspipe`, what is issue with UART?

I edit */etc/default/gpsd* file.

```sh
    # Default settings for gpsd.
    # Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd' to
    # change the options.
            START_DAEMON="true" command to continue
            GPSD_OPTIONS=""
            DEVICES="/dev/ttyS1"
            USBAUTO="false"
            GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

but I am not getting NMEA data using `gpsd`...

Comment: Are you sure the module doesn't require any firmware or use vendor specific protocol?

Comment: no . it doesnt require any firmware , anything i am missing in gpsd configuration .